# Select values in timerange based on timepoint addition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a given the table below and I want to extract for all ids the first salary and the salary after two years. If the person hasn't stayed for two years, IDs and salaries shouldn't appear in the selection.
As can be seen in the table, the IDs can appear in several rows but they are always sorted chronologically.
Top of the table:

```
+=======+========+============+=============+
|  id   | salary | from_date  |  to_date    |
+=======+========+============+=============+
| 10001 |  60117 | 1986-06-26 | 1987-06-26  |
| 10001 |  62102 | 1987-06-26 | 1988-06-25  |
| 10001 |  66074 | 1988-06-25 | 1989-06-25  |
| 10001 |  66596 | 1989-06-25 | 1990-06-25  |
| 10001 |  66961 | 1990-06-25 | 1991-06-25  |
| 10001 |  71046 | 1991-06-25 | 1992-06-24  |
| 10001 |  74333 | 1992-06-24 | 1993-06-24  |
| 10001 |  75286 | 1993-06-24 | 1994-06-24  |
| 10001 |  75994 | 1994-06-24 | 1995-06-24  |
| 10001 |  76884 | 1995-06-24 | 1996-06-23  |
| 10001 |  80013 | 1996-06-23 | 1997-06-23  |
| 10001 |  81025 | 1997-06-23 | 1998-06-23  |
| 10001 |  81097 | 1998-06-23 | 1999-06-23  |
| 10001 |  84917 | 1999-06-23 | 2000-06-22  |
| 10001 |  85112 | 2000-06-22 | 2001-06-22  |
| 10001 |  85097 | 2001-06-22 | 2002-06-22  |
| 10001 |  88958 | 2002-06-22 | 9999-01-01  |
| 10002 |  65828 | 1996-08-03 | 1997-08-03  |
| 10002 |  65909 | 1997-08-03 | 1998-08-03  |
+-------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

The output should be in the format:
ID, salary (at entry), salary (two years after entry)

For the first ID:
10001, 60117, 66074

Currently I have only managed to extract all IDs who have stayed longer than 2 two years but I don't know how to select the salaries for the start and exactly after two years for each ID.

```
SELECT id, min(from_date), max(to_date)
FROM salaries
GROUP BY id
HAVING DATE_ADD(min(from_date), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)  < max(to_date)
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and provide sample results.

Comment: Ok, I've added information about the output format.